# Implicit declaration of functions warning

Tags: c, warnings, clang

I'm trying to use the functions `isDigit()` I have the correct include statement, `#include <ctype.h>` however, I seem to be getting a warning when I compile,

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'isDigit' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

The line that compiles the warning is `if(isDigit(atoi(inputLine)) {` can anyone give me feedback as to what I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: `isDigit()` is not a standard library function!

Comment: I saw the same message for isdigit with lower case d. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the function is `isdigit()`, not `isDigit()`. C is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

include this header file in your program : **#include<ctype.h>**